# setting up azure ad certificate auth using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to setup an Azure AD application to authenticate using a certificate. I have been using [this guide](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/user-app-app-only-permissions-client-credentials-grant-flow-in-azure-ad-office-365-apis) to successfully set this up after failing following [this guide](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/Daemon-CertificateCredential-DotNet).

I wish to now automate the process so it can be added to our general build scripts, looking at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986794.aspx) for the `New-AzureADApplication` command it includes a parameter set(ApplicationWithKeyCredentialParameterSet) that takes a `PSADKeyCredential`. using this to create an application and then downloading the metadata gives me the following

```
"keyCredentials": [
{
  "customKeyIdentifier": null,
  "endDate": "2015-12-31T11:00:00Z",
  "keyId": "586b4d3e-84cf-43ec-a913-a33ef5075fdc",
  "startDate": "2004-12-31T12:00:00Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
}
```

]

If I use the ApplicationWithKeyPlainParameterSet I get the same result. Does anyone know why I am getting a null Value field? If there is a different way I should be setting up the certificates I'm open to changing my process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'value' field for the key credentials is always returned as 'null' for applications and service principals.

Comment: You're correct, despite the metadata returning null for the 'value' the credentials are added successfully.